# PHP Parse Errors?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting a parse error (unexpected T_Else) when trying to utilize the following code in my wordpress website. Any clue what it could be? Sorry new to PHP so bear with me.

```
<?php 
if (time() >= strtotime('11/28/2011') && time() <= strtotime('12/25/2011')) 
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s10_Nov28-Dec25.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('12/26/2011') && time() <= strtotime('01/14/2012'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s11_Dec26-Jan14.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('01/15/2011') && time() <= strtotime('02/14/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s2_Jan15-Feb14.php');
 } 
else if (time() >= strtotime('02/15/2011') && time() <= strtotime('03/17/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s3_Feb15-Mar17.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('03/18/2011') && time() <= strtotime('04/30/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s4_Mar18-Apr30.php');

else if (time() >= strtotime('05/01/2011') && time() <= strtotime('05/30/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s5_May01-May30.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('06/01/2011') && time() <= strtotime('07/04/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s6_Jun01-Jul04.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('07/05/2011') && time() <= strtotime('08/31/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s7_Jul05-Aug31.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('09/01/2011') && time() <= strtotime('10/31/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s8_Sep01-Oct31.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('11/27/2011') && time() <= strtotime('11/27/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s9_Nov01-Nov27.php');
 }
?>
```

Comment: Does the error message give any indication of location of the error? It's generally a good idea to paste the exact error message into the question. Also, a generally good approach is to cut down your code to something smaller, and see if the problem still happens. If it still happens, you've got a more convenient example to show people. If the problem goes away, you've learned something useful about the problem (namely that it's somehow related to the material you cut out).

Comment: You know `else if` should be `elseif` as one word?

Comment: @Jonno_FTW: It *can* be one word, it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a missing close brace just after the "'/stub_s4_Mar18-Apr30.php')" line, which is most likely causing this issue.

Incidentally, you might want to store the current time in a variable rather than making repeated calls to the time() function. I'd also be tempted to use [require_once](http://www.php.net/require_once), unless you specifically don't mind if the include fails.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the closing `}` at line 17:

```
<?php 
if (time() >= strtotime('11/28/2011') && time() <= strtotime('12/25/2011')) 
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s10_Nov28-Dec25.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('12/26/2011') && time() <= strtotime('01/14/2012'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s11_Dec26-Jan14.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('01/15/2011') && time() <= strtotime('02/14/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s2_Jan15-Feb14.php');
 } 
else if (time() >= strtotime('02/15/2011') && time() <= strtotime('03/17/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s3_Feb15-Mar17.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('03/18/2011') && time() <= strtotime('04/30/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s4_Mar18-Apr30.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('05/01/2011') && time() <= strtotime('05/30/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s5_May01-May30.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('06/01/2011') && time() <= strtotime('07/04/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s6_Jun01-Jul04.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('07/05/2011') && time() <= strtotime('08/31/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s7_Jul05-Aug31.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('09/01/2011') && time() <= strtotime('10/31/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s8_Sep01-Oct31.php');
 }
else if (time() >= strtotime('11/27/2011') && time() <= strtotime('11/27/2011'))
 { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/stub_s9_Nov01-Nov27.php');
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The fifth `if` block appears to be missing a close bracket.